# Jenkins Post Build Publish JUnit Results not getting all files

Tags: junit, jenkins, fileset

I've got files stored in my workspace as:

- selenium-tests/results/results-0.xml
- selenium-tests/results/results-1.xml
- selenium-tests/results/results-2.xml
- selenium-tests/results/results-3.xml
- selenium-tests/results/results-4.xml

I'm publishing JUnit test results with the fileset pattern: `**/results/results-*.xml`.  All five files aren't present in the test results.  It's also never the same result files included.

These are three runs back to back to back with the same exact configuration and tests.  They're failing because our staging environment is down right now.
[image: JUnit results]

I've even gone as far as `**/results/results-0.xml, **/results/results-1.xml, **/results/results-2.xml, **/results/results-3.xml, **/results/results-4.xml` and am still having the same issues.

Comment: Just to note, I've also tried `selenium-tests/results/results-*.xml`.

Comment: Can you show the exact error? As for now I see no reason how `selenium-tests/results/results-*.xml` will not work. The only guess is in escaping a dash, but I have not tried. Can you try `**/results/results*.xml` ?

Comment: I'll give it a shot.  There is no actual error other than it's not picking up some of the files.  The build is unstable (test failures) not a failure.  Jenkin's output in the console is: `Recording test results
Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE`

Comment: So, yes, when any of the unit test is failing, junit reporter will change build to unstable. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24655 Then your artifacts are not even starting archiving.

Comment: I was just stating everything is working as expected (other than the test reporting).  For further clarity, it's a custom job, not a maven job.  But I tried `**/results*.xml` and it still missed some files.

Comment: Looks like it relates to: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18696

Comment: As a workaround, I started using the `junit_merge` gem.